# Is a C# Query needed to use the set operations?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

When I was searching for a way to get the difference between two lists I came across this page: [Set operations (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/set-operations).

I found out, that I can use the `Except` method. But what confused me in this code example:

```cs
string[] planets1 = { "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Jupiter" };
string[] planets2 = { "Mercury", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter" };

IEnumerable<string> query = from planet in planets1.Except(planets2)
                            select planet;

foreach (var str in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}

/* This code produces the following output:
 *
 * Venus
 */
```

was this line: `IEnumerable<string> query = from planet in planets1.Except(planets2) select planet;`

Considering that I’m very new to C#, my question is, do you need this query to use the Except method? This line seems to do the same thing: `IEnumerable<string> query = planets1.Except(planets2);`

Am I missing something here?

Comment: No, that's an unfortunate example. Personally I only use the query expression form when the query gets complex with joins etc... it's always fine to just use method calls.

Comment: Consider also using [`HashSet<string>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1) here. It has set operations as well and is much faster (at least for big sets).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Thanks :). The sets I'm using have over 100K elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write LINQ in two way

1. query expression like form

   ```
   IEnumerable<string> query = from planet in planets1.Except(planets2)
                                select planet;
   ```
2. Method chain form

   ```
   IEnumerable<string> query = planets1.Except(planets2)
                                    .Select(planet => planet);
   ```

In query expression form, group clause or select clause must exists but in method chain form you do not need to end with select method.

So both of these code return `IEnumerable<string[]>`

```
planets1.Except(planets2)
```

and

```
planets1.Except(planets2).Select(planet => planet)
```